# Sum of the Raster Cell Values Located in the Polygon

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, raster-calculator

I have two layers:

- The first one is a raster containing values of built covered area for example it has 100x100 (10000 meter square) cells if the cell carries the value 1328 it means that in that cell 1328 meter square area is covered with builts.
- and the second layer is a vector, a polygon of my study areas. My study areas are 33 different cities and they are in one layer.

I want to calculate the built-up coverage of each city in my study area, which means the sum of the values in the raster and in the boundary of each cities.

Do you have any suggestions to do that? Actually, I can do it with a long way but I have several raster files from different years so I need to find the easiest way.

[image: QGIS screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Zonal Statistics](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgiszonalstatisticsfb):

> Calculates statistics of a raster layer for each feature of an
> overlapping polygon vector layer.

[image]